# как считать информацию из txt файла в словарь из python3

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, dict

Как можно обработать информацию из файла с данной структурой, записав ее в словарь python 3 (учитывая тот факт, что данные в каждой вложенной структуре могут меняться)? Например, могут добавляться или удаляться новые вершины, новые hex блоки, новые части внутри блока boundary

```
convertToMeters 0.1;
vertices
(
  ( 0.0 0.0 0.0)
  ( 0.0 2.0 0.0)
  ( 0.0 2.0 5.0)
  ( 0.0 .0 5.0)
  ( 1.0 0.0 0.0)
  ( 1.0 2.0 0.0)
  ( 0.0 2.0 5.0)
  ( 1.0 0.0 5.0)
);
blocks
( hex
  ( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7) ( 20 20 1) simpleGrading ( 1 1 1)
);
edges
(
);
boundary
(
movingWall
{
    type wall;
    faces
    (
      ( 3 7 6 2)
    );
}

fixedWalls
{
    type wall;
    faces
    (
      ( 0 4 7 3)
      ( 2 6 5 1)
      ( 1 5 4 0)
    );
}

frontAndBack
{
    type empty;
    faces
    (
      ( 0 3 2 1)
      ( 4 5 6 7)
    );
}

);
mergePatchPairs
(
);
```

Comment: Проще всего найти готовый парсер, но для этого нужно знать, откуда вы этот файл взяли.

Comment: Нет готового парсера. Это файл из директории эксперимента OpenFOM (используется для решения задач механики сплошных сред). Мне нужно данные из этого файла загружать в экранные формы

Comment: А это не оно случайно? https://github.com/ApolloLV/openfoamparser